# Is it halal to work for a software company for operating systems?

Tags: halal-haram, work, software

Is it halal to work for a software company which provides operating systems to laptops, smartphones (Microsoft)?  As a software engineer or as a software developer?

Answer (score 2):

```
                                   In the name of Allah
```

Actually, I agree with M.Ali's answer concerning your question as you asked

> Is it halal to work for a software company which provides operating
>   systems to laptops,smartphones(Microsoft) as a software engineer or as
>   a software developer? Please let me know

In truth, it won't be considered as a haram business in case that the software which you are developing isn't counted as a part of any haram goal. Therefore by paying heed to this issue, it can be declared that it can be permissible.

And Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

If the software you are developing isn't being used for any haram purposes like gambling, pornography, selling haram substance (alcohol, etc), banking, etc., then I don't see any reason why it would be haram.